# Unexpected behavior with PHP function_exists

Tags: php

I have two files.

file1.php:

```
require_once 'file2.php';
FOO();
```

file2.php:

```
if (!function_exists("FOO"))
{
   function FOO()
   {
   ...
   }
...
}
```

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function FOO() in file1.php

I've taken out the function_exists() call and everything works fine. Am I misusing function_exists()?

Comment: @Soujirou To avoid re-declarations.

Comment: @Soujirou Because one would only want to declare a function if it does not exist.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that you are misusing function_exists. However when I run file1.php from the command-line it works as expected. How are you running these scripts?

Comment: Could you give some more details, as I tried to reconstruct the problem, but it worked just fine for me.
Are you sure you are not forgetting the <?php tags in file2?

Comment: Are you sure you have `require_once()` then `FOO();` in that order in the first script, and not the other way around?

Comment: With the help of comments here I figured out that true problem was that I created a loop of includes.  Sorry to waste everyone's time.